# POST multiple files using Django test client in same request

Tags: python, django, testing, post, integration-testing

I am trying to build some tests for uploads on my Django site. It allows multiple files to be uploaded so I need to test when multiple files are uploaded.

Testing one file works great:

```
from django.test import Client

def test_stuff(self): 
    with open('....\file.csv','rb') as fp:
        c = Client()
        response = c.post('/', {'name': 'Some Name', 'email': 'some@email.com', 'file': fp})
```

But trying it with a list of files doesn't work.

```
def test_stuff(self): 
    file_list = # get list of file paths to open
    myfiles = []
    for file in file_list:
        with open('....\file.csv','rb') as fp:
            myfiles.append(fp)
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/', {'name': 'Some Name', 'email': 'some@email.com', 'file':myfiles})
```

And neither does:

```
def test_stuff(self): 
    file_list = # get list of file paths to open
    myfiles = []
    for file in file_list:
        with open('....\file.csv','rb') as fp:
            myfiles.append(fp)
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/', {'name': 'Some Name', 'email': 'some@email.com',}, files={'file':myfiles})
```

or

```
def test_stuff(self): 
    file_list = # get list of file paths to open
    myfiles = []
    for file in file_list:
        with open('....\file.csv','rb') as fp:
            myfiles.append(fp)
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/', {'name': 'Some Name', 'email': 'some@email.com'}, files=myfiles)
```

My view gets the files from `request.POST.get('myfiles')`, but `FILES` is empty.

Is there a way to POST multiple files with django test client or should I use something else?

> Edited to make more accurate

Comment: A comment in my Reddit question informed me it isn't a list of files, so I looked at my AJAX call in the production code and realized it's building a set. I'm going to try that today in python and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem was that with `with`, the file is immediately closed exiting the statement. Unsurprisingly, the other part was getting the data in the correct format. Django's test client wants ALL the data as a dictionary so, since i was also sending the username and email, it needed to be formatted like:

```
def test_stuff(self): 
    file_list = # get list of file paths to open
    data = {}
    files = []
    for file in file_list:
        fp = open('....\file.csv','rb')
        files.append(fp)
    data['myfiles'] = files
    data['name'] = 'Some Name'
    data['email'] = 'some@email.com'
    c = Client()
    response = c.post('/', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you use `SimpleUploadedFile` you can pass multiple files:

```py
file1 = SimpleUploadedFile('file1.txt', b'file-1')
file2 = SimpleUploadedFile('file2.txt', b'file-2')

response = self.client.post('some url', data={
  'file': [ file1, file2]
})
```

And in the view it could be smth like:

```py
class UploadFormView(FormView):
    template_name = '...'
    form_class = YourForm

    # We require to override the post method to manage multiple files.
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
              # do smth with file
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable.